# How set height layout dependig text length?

Tags: android, android-layout, height

I have got Scrolview,Layout and TextView.

```
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/Layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@null"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

How set height layout dependig text length ?? If text is short, layout  height should be equal screen height.But when text is long(for example more 100 sentences) layout height schould be greater than screen height and schould depend on the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your layout and that should scale it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView`, and set the children `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. (Referred from [ScrollView's handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/))

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/Layout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@null"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```